# How to check each value in a row in a pandas dataframe for a certain condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe:

```
   one  two
a  1.0  7.0
b  2.0  2.0
c  3.0  3.0
d  6.0  4.0
```

What I would like to do is to check for example for index a if each of the values in the columns is greater than 4. If one of the values is indeed greater the system prints the message that in "column name" value "x" is greater than 4. How can I accomplish that ?

Comment: This is so basic that surely you can read a Pandas tutorial and try it.

Comment: Indeed basic but I couldn't figure it out from the Pandas documentation. I just want to automatically check every single records from row a for a certain value. I can't find the answer in "Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas".